# Question on copying data from one open workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, temp

I am looking to copy a range of data (columns A:M) on a temporary excel worksheet, with a "tmp" prefix into a worksheet designed to crunch all of this data output into a useable report.

Currently, the user will simply manually copy the temporary output into the report making tool, then run the macro.

Is it possible to automate this data input?

Comment: basically, you want to copy from one worksheet to another?

Comment: yes. from one open worksheet to another

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Have you tried any code on your own yet?  SO is not really a place for others to write your code for you.  I would start with using the Macro Recorder, which isnt great, but it will give you an idea on where to start.

Comment: will the macro recorder register me moving into different worksheets/windows?

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, SO is used for teaching. But, since I got bored, and in case you don't re-post this here, this is an ***idea*** of how to accomplish your goal. Keep in mind that with VBA, and probably all other languages, there's 20 different ways to accomplish the same task, but what fits each users unique scenario is what SO likes to resolve. To give you a rolling start and perhaps some motivation...

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyStuff()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As New Worksheet
Dim rngToCopy As Range
Dim ShtName As String

'use ActiveSheet or actual name
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngToCopy = ws.UsedRange.Columns("A:M")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

'gets name for sheet
ShtName = InputBox("Please enter name for Sheet.")

'more properties to fill if needed, or adjust area to copy to
'just an example here
With ws2
    .Name = "tmp" & ShtName
    rngToCopy.Copy .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1)
End With

'cleanup
Set ws = nothng: Set ws2 = Nothing
Set rngToCopy = Nothing: ShtName = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Danny,

[ExcelVBADude](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA?view_as=subscriber)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.  I know Stack overflow is used for teaching, but I didn't really know where to start on this task.